# $+x = x$ (A mathematical convention?)

Tags: notation

It seems to me that, by convention, the equality $+x = x$ holds for any real (or complex) number $x$.

I have not, however, found such a convention explicitly presented in any text.

Well... am I wrong and there is no such convention?

Comment: Well if $+x$ isn't $x$ by definition, then what else would it be? What prompted you to ask this question?

Comment: Well... I still haven't found in the literature that, by definition, +x = x.
However, I've seen things like this:
+(+2) = 2 , +(-5) = -5, etc.
Since x and y are real numbers, given the equation |x| = |y|, it is customary to write: x = ± y, that is, x = +y = y  or  x = -y.

Comment: @PauloArgolo You can think of $0+2=+2$ as a notation symmetric to $0-2=-2$.

Comment: In my opinion the reason $+x$ never needs to be defined (other than that it's obvious) is that it's not actually used but in cases where one wishes to emphasize that we are speaking of $+$ and not $-$. If you were to write a computer verifiable proof you would omit the $+$, it is used not for a mathematical purpose but for a human purpose, for emphasis. (As for the $\pm$ symbol, $\pm x$ is defined to mean both options: $x$ and $-x$. Which according to the convention, you can also write as $+x$ and $-x$ if you wish.)

Comment: I don’t think that I would ever write “$+x$” by itself. It’s probably hard to find this explicitly defined because mathematicians never actually write this.

Comment: @PauloArgolo But why would there be any need to formally define '$+x$'? As Snaw says,  it is just used for emphasis

Comment: One instance where this notation commonly occurs is when working with the extended reals and one may write something like $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}f(x)=+\infty$, but again, one just as often writes $\sup_{x}f(x)=\infty$.

Comment: You can say that $+x = (+1)(x) \Leftrightarrow +x = x$.

Comment: @VeryForgetfulFunctor "What else would it be?"  Some beginners may think that $+x$ means what mathematicians write as  $|x|$.

Comment: @dxiv  Yes . I've already found in the literature -x as shorthand for 0 - x , as well as +x for short for 0 + x.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. You can think of this as a statement about
the identity. That is define the identity function
$$ +x = (+1)\, x = \iota(x) := x $$ parallel to the negation function
$$ -x = (-1)\, x = \nu(x) := -x. $$

It can also be used for consistency and emphasis in equations such as
$$ -y + x = +x - y. $$ There may be more reasons for it being used but
you are correct that

> I have not, however, found such a convention explicitly presented in any text.

Perhaps the reason is that it is so obvious that it seems not to be
needed to state explicitly. However, in the context of computer-aid
proof and computation, in order that it will be correctly understood
and processed, there needs to be explicit rules to recognize such  expressions but they will be used internally and not likely to be
explicitly documented as such.